# How to auto adjust width of a wpf textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'd like my textbox to have a width that will fit exactly the size of the text within it.

So if there's just one character within it it'll be a small width.
And if there's a long word within it it'll be a long width, etc.

Is this possible, and if so-- how can I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

That is the default behavior of a TextBox, however the parent panel for the TextBox can affect a TextBox's size.

For example, a `Grid` will automatically stretch it's children to fill all available space. A `DockPanel` will do the same with the Last Child added to it, unless `LastChildFill=False`.

You can overwrite this behavior in the parent panel by setting the `HorizontalAlignment` of the TextBox. For example, setting `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` will center the TextBox inside a `Grid` rather than stretching it to fill all remaining space

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the container the `TextBox` is in, but typically if you set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` you will get this behavior.

However, if it's (for example) the last element in the `DockPanel` with the `LastChildFill` property set to true, then the `DockPanel` will stretch it out for you.